# Untamed Berserker Style and Cleave hitting a solo enemy

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, fighter, hit-points

I just had a quick question, which they touch on [in this EN World thread](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?248547-New-Cleave-feat-question) but I'd just like a second opinion.

Can I gain the temp HP from Untamed Berserker Style and Cleave if there's only one enemy adjacent to me (the one I'm hitting)? My first impression would be no, but I could see where you could not need a second enemy adjacent to you for the power to work.

Comment: So, I have another question to add onto this, if I also take Criterian of Baltic Practice, can I choose which I can do first when I'm a polearm fighter with Polearm Momentum, Longhand student and use Cleave?

Example: Thinking in terms of a compass, I'm in the spot south, the enemy is in a spot north. I hit him with Cleave. Do I have to push him 2 squares and knock him prone, then shift my square, or can I choose to use the Baltic Practice ability first, shift to either the west or east spots, and then I'm able to push him in directions I wouldn't have been able to by pushing first?

Answer (score 1):

I Googled the quote for the wording on Cleave, and the damage is applied to, "an enemy adjacent to you other than the target".
Since moving the original target and/or yourself doesn't turn it into an enemy other than itself, I would have to say that you cannot perform the Cleave action in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When referring to a rule, you should specify the source of it (which rulebook contains it, possibly incluing page number). Referring to google only means that "you can find it *somewhere*", which is not too helpful for others. I encourage you to visit our faq/help to learn more.